# How to deal with non-square pixels in QtQuick?

Tags: qt, qtquick2

X and Y coordinates have different units. It's hard to track.

Screen is 15cm x 8cm with resolution 800x480. QScreen reports different values for logicalDotsPerInchX and logicalDotsPerInchY as expected. QML reports 800x480 pixels, takes coordinates in pixels and draws as QML does.

Can some pixel-independent coordinates be used?

Why QML is bound to pixels? It's more natural to have floating-point coordinates since we are already in the OpenGL.

If you scale the root element, you have a nice normal basis. But it's scaling: fonts don't survive.

Comment: What's the actual, concrete problem?

Comment: To make the application look like it looks on the desktop monitor. Right now it is stretched in the vertical dimension.

Comment: Ok, so start by showing us a screenshot of the application on your device.

Comment: Not possible today and not necessary. Screen is 15cm x 8cm with resolution 800x480. QScreen reports different values for logicalDotsPerInchX and logicalDotsPerInchY as expected. QML reports  800x480 pixels, takes coordinates in pixels and renders accordingly as expected (as a result, the square becomes a rectangle because the pixels are rectangular).

Comment: It is necessary if you don't have information like what you just gave us in your question...

Comment: Another option is to believe that I'm smart enough to recognize non-square pixels. Added info to the question.

Comment: Wow. The ego of some people. Who said anything about questioning your intellect? This site is about solving problems, and up until your last comment, which should have been part of your original question, there was nothing that we had to go by to help solve your problem.